# c++ template NULL undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree

I am having problems in c++ with templates and NULL. I am trying to make a BST in c++ using templates. I have a class element, treeElement and binarySearchTree.

A binarySearchTree has treeElements as nodes. Each treeElement has a linkedList of elements. Each element has also a long to indentify and check whether it's <, > or ==.

Now I get the error: NULL undeclared identifier. I don't know how it's possible. Here's my code of treeElement where I get the error:

```
template <class T>
class TreeElement {
private:
    TreeElement* leftTree;
    TreeElement* rightTree;
    TreeElement* parent;
    Element<T>* value;
public:
    //Here is the error!!
    TreeElement(Element<T>* element){value = element; leftTree = NULL; rightTree = NULL; parent = NULL;};
    ~TreeElement() {
        Element<T>* nextElement;
        if (value != NULL) {
            while (value->getNextElement() != NULL) {
                nextElement = value;
                value = nextElement->getNextElement();
                delete nextElement;
            }
            delete value;
        }
    };
    TreeElement* getLeftTree(){return this->leftTree;};
    TreeElement* getRightTree(){return this->rightTree;};
    TreeElement* getParent(){return this->parent;};
    Element<T>* getValue(){return this->value;};

    void setLeftTree(TreeElement* leftTree){this->leftTree = leftTree;};
    void setRightTree(TreeElement* rightTree){this->rightTree = rightTree;};
    void setParent(TreeElement* parent){this->parent = parent;};
    void setValue(Element<T>* value){this->value = value;};
};
```

Comment: `#include <cstddef>`, or use `nullptr`

Comment: Or just use `nullptr` if possible, it is preferable to `NULL` which is just a macro for `0`;

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can you please explain me, why it's nessecary? Because, when I usually code in c++ my compiler knows by itself what is means. Only now, it doesn't

Comment: *"my compiler knows by itself what is means"* no it does not. `NULL` is not a keyword (a part of language grammar itself), it's macro definition, defined in `cstddef` header file, possibly included indirectly, what made you think this "should always work". However, `nullptr` is a keyword, and should be preferred to `NULL` or `0` (starting from C++11)

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

- include the header `<cstddef>` which defines `NULL`
- use a null pointer constant, `0` or (since C++11) `nullptr` rather than a dodgy macro
- don't compare with null, just use the pointer itself in a boolean context for the same effect (although that only applies to one of your uses of `NULL` here)

Comment: The last suggestion is pure obfuscation.  Not something you want to see in professionally written code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's your opinion, but not mine. Contextual conversion to `bool` is well defined, and as clear as any other language construct if you're familiar with the concept.

Comment: The 3rd point will not work in this case as `NULL` is also used in the constructor for the initial values.

Comment: @ArtakBegnazaryan: Indeed, it will only work for one of the uses here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It's well defined at the language level, but it is lying to the person who reads the code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's your opinion, but not mine. Lets not get into a pointless argument about programming aesthetics.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, other languages like Ruby often use the rule that asking if the pointer/reference is null rather than using it as a boolean is just too verbose and provides no information to the reader. This is entirely opinion based so all these comments will be vacuumed.